# Use Javascript to Change Display Styles (CSS) Without Affecting Print Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I have a web application that utilizes a separate [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) to control how the page looks when it comes out of the printer.  That was working wonderfully until I recently made some Javascript enhancements to the site.  One of these enhancements allows the user to freeze the page header and navigation, as well as table headers.  The Javascript behind this does some CSS trickery to freeze the elements on the screen.  Unfortunately, applying `position: fixed` to my header (for example) causes it to print on every page, and this is not a desired effect.  How can I use Javascript to tweak element styles on the client-side without affecting the print style?

```
@media print { #foo { color: blue; } }               /* Print definition */
@media screen { #foo { color: green; } }             /* Display definition */
document.getElementById('foo').style.color = 'red';  /* Overrides both! */
```

Comment: Note: A lot of the styles I change with Javascript are not even set in the CSS print file.  Ideally, I would have a way to change *only display* styles in Javascript.  Having to manually override all the JS tweaks in the CSS print file with `!important` is not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good solution!  What I ended up doing is utilizing the `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` functions in IE (I am in the position here that we only have IE users) to "unfreeze" and "refreeze" the elements...

```
window.onbeforeprint = function() {
  document.getElementById('foo').style.position = 'static';
}

window.onload = window.onafterprint = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('foo');
  // Get element position and size
  // Set left/top/width/height properties
  // Set position to fixed
  el.style.position = 'fixed';
}
```

Comment: [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) does something similar to enable support for printing HTML5 elements in the older versions of IE. So, the technique is robust.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing properties on your elements with this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.color = 'red';
```

append a new `<style>` element, for example:

```
$('<style>@media screen { #foo { color: green; } }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

It would be better to concatenate all your required changes into one `<style>` element, if possible.

Comment: Great idea.  I have tested this on IE6, IE9, Chrome and FF5.

Answer (score 2):

Add `!important` to your print rules.

Comment: Huh?  That's not going to do anything.  I don't even set `position` (or any of the other things I am tweaking with Javascript) in my CSS rules.

Comment: I suppose this means I will have to override every style I tweak with Javascript?  I can see where that's headed!  So next year when I have to change the Javascript I will forget to change the CSS override... Ug-leeeee

Comment: By the way, I tried adding this and set `position: static !important` to avoid the fixed positioning on print, and now it crashes IE every single time I try to print or preview!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
    @media print { #foo { color: blue !important; } }

The problem is that javascript .style.something,  edits the inline css of the element, therefore it will override the normal css class/id rules.

Or you can, work with classes.
    document.getElementById('foo').className = 'redText';

and keep the .redText in your regular css file (not the print one), much much better than filling your print css with !important rules.

Comment: Thanks for the more complete answer.  I'm sad there's not a cleaner way, something like `document.getElementById('foo').displayStyle.color = 'green';`

Comment: Unfortunately there is not, no. But working with classes is actually very clean. Because when you get back later to do some maintenance you will find all the styling rules in the CSS (where they semantically belong),  instead of having to edit both your CSS and JS file.

Comment: Not really an option.  If you think about freezing an element on the page, you have to fix the position, and then set its precise coordinates within the parent.  If the content of these elements varies from page to page, you can't predict the size it will take up (if you are using any sort of flow layout), so the changes have to be made dynamically in Javascript.  I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, then you might want to try this,
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3817

Create and append css rules with javascript. I am not sure if it works on all browsers. But it is certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is not to poke styles onto nodes, but to instead tie your screen-specific style tweaks to css classes that only affect your screen rendition of things:

`@media screen { .freeze { position: fixed; } } /* Display-only definition */`

+

`document.getElementById('foo').className = "freeze";`

As a bonus, this also makes it easy to change tons of styles with just one line of js, which makes things faster and easier to maintain, too.